# Ignore navigation property when mapping in Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Having these 2 classes as an example:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int CategoryId {get; set;}
}

public class ProductDTO
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int CategoryId {get; set;}
    public Category Category {get; set;}
}
```

How can I ignore `ProductDTO.Category` when mapping bidrectionally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you mean bi-directional i.e. both classes have a `Category` member that you want to ignore you can use `.ReverseMap()`.

**Mappings**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductDTO>()                
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Category, opt => opt.Ignore()).ReverseMap();
```

**Example Models**

```
public class Product
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public int CategoryId {get; set;}
        public Category Category {get; set;}
    }

    public class ProductDTO
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public int CategoryId {get; set;}
        public Category Category {get; set;}
    }

    public class Category
    {

    }
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cs2F7C)**